# Leaflet catch window position

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geolocation

This is what I want to do:

When loading the map, it will first grab the window coordinates of the current screen, and then load the data points of the current screen.
  The next screen is as described above, but the data of the previous screen will be cleared.

I think make the performance worse when loading too much data,so I want to do this problem.

To put it simply, it means that only the screen that moves to it appears, and the data of that screen appears.

This is my code:

```
<script>

    var osmUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, { maxZoom: 25, attribution: osmAttrib });
    var map = L.map('map').setView([24.151687694799833, 120.64116954803465], 25).addLayer(osm);
    L.control.scale().addTo(map);


    function onLocationFound(e) {
        var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

        L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

        L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
    }

    function onLocationError(e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

    map.locate({ setView: true, maxZoom: 15 });


    /*try to catch window position*/
    var top = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
        left = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;



    var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
        radius: 8,
        fillColor: "#FF3333 ", //#ff7800
        color: "#000",
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.8
    };

    $.getJSON("taiwan.json", function (data) {
        var datalayer = L.geoJson(data, {
            onEachFeature: function (feature, featureLayer) {
                featureLayer.bindPopup("編號: " + feature.properties.id +
                    "</br>時間: " + feature.properties.date +
                    "</br>規模: " + feature.properties.magnitude);
            },
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
            }
        }).addTo(map);
        //map.fitBounds(datalayer.getBounds());
    });

</script>
```

Now,I don't know how can I catch window position,and combine the data I load.

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What's the original problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @IvanSanchez has a nice plugin for what seems to be your problem: Leaflet.VectorGrid at https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid.

Comment: @TomazicM  Sorry,did you know what can I do this?  
To catch window position.

Comment: What do you mean by "catch"? Are you attempting to get the current map bounds? https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-getbounds And then use that to pre-filter your data?

Comment: Yes,but I don't know what I can do.Can you speak in datail? Thank you!

Comment: Leaflet.VectorGrid plugin is not intended to catch window position but to solve what seems to be your problem: to load on map only those GeoJSON elements that are visible.